# UE4: PhAt is acting weird

Tags: game-physics, unreal-engine4

You can see my problem in the image:
[image]

My mesh ist deforming like crazy and I dont know what to do to fix this.
Would be geat if you woud have a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your ragdolls are not correctly set, you should set your ragdolls in Maya or Phat.

Check out [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10j4jn4VXxA&list=PLZlv_N0_O1gaHlJrP4F12Px7ceHw3PDq-)

If you want to figure out which rigid body are wrong set, you can set the Physics Type to Kinematic and see if other rigid body act right.